# Hitman pro is suspicious of these three files... should I be worried?

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, malware

My anti malware software "hitman pro" uses heuristics to highlight suspicious files. It is highlighting the following three, all within c:\windows\system32

mpcdx.ax
rlapedec.ax
rlmpcdec.ax

Hitman pro has never complained about these files before. I don't know if that's because they're newly added or newly modified.

Should I be worried?

P.S. I recently installed erightsoft's "super" program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the files through [VirusTotal](http://www.virustotal.com/).

Answer (score 4):

These are codec files. A google search finds a lot of people asking the same thing. Apparently AdAware hits on them too. They seem to be OK though.

Answer (score 2):

Well [this page](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/filedb/rlmpcdec.ax-41540.html) claims that `rlmpcdec.ax` is

> RadLight MPC DirectShow Filter

and [this page](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/filedb/rlapedec.ax-41539.html) that `rlapedec.ax` is

> RadLight APE DirectShow Filter

You can check the file properties to see if the file has been added to your system recently. There's a good chance they were added by "Super", but it would be worth checking with eRightSoft.